# Why does this variant of comb space have no universal cover?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ = Comb Space union $\{y=1, 0\leq x \leq 1\}$.

Comb space refers to the standard union of $0 \times I$, $I \times 0$ and $\{1/n\}\times I$ where $I = [0,1]$.

Why does this space NOT have a simply connected cover?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't have a simply connected covering?

Comment: well at least that's what I have been asked to show. 
So far I can see it is itself not simply connected (unlike the comb space)